# Perform different actions with a button based on the data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, custom-data-attribute

I have one button. His first action is to stop a video. Then it's icon change and data-status too. His second action is to reload the page.

The problem is that I can't do the second even if I code some conditions. Sometimes it don't do anything, sometimes the second action comes at the same time of the first one.

Here is my Jquery code:

```
// STOP VIDEO (ACTION 1)
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#button').attr({
        src: 'img/film.png',
        'data-status':'stop'
    });
}); 

// RELOAD (ACTION 2)
$("#button[data-status='stop']").click(function() {
    location.reload();
});

// OTHER METHOD FOR RELOAD (ACTION 2)
if ($("#button").data( "status", "stop" )) {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<img id="button" src="skip.png" data-status="play">
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By binding the click event multiple times, you're firing both the functions on the second click. Instead, you should put the logic that decides to stop/reload inside the one event callback:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var button = $(this);

    if(button.attr('data-status') === 'stop') {
        // Already stopped
        location.reload();

    } else {
        // Stop
        button.attr({
            src: 'img/film.png',
            'data-status':'stop'
        )};
    }
)};
```